# ¿Cómo dejo un espacio en blanco apto en cualquier vista con Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy empezando a practicar diseño responsivo con Bootstrap para armar un portafolio.

El problema que tengo es el siguiente:

Quiero poner un título que esté a una distancia razonable de la foto de perfil que se ve en la imagen. Dicha distancia no debe superponerse al título y tiene que ser la misma tanto para dispositivos móviles como para pantallas más grandes, pero lo que intenté se "rompe" al achicar la pantalla, adjunto imágenes:

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

Adjunto código HTML

```
<div class="container bg-primary">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 position-relative border">
  <div class="position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle">
    <span class="rounded-circle">
      <img src="./assets/img/fotocv.png" class="rounded-circle img-fluid border-dark border border-1" id="fotocv" alt="">
    </span>
  </div>
  <h1 class="border-bottom border-danger fs-4 pb-2 border-4 rounded text-uppercase" id="nombre">Facundo Nicolas Duran</h1>
  <p>Estudiante de Ingeniería en Sistemas de Información</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Desconozco si deseas poner algo a la derecha de la imagen (Algún otro texto o algo en la misma fila (Posición horizontal), en dado caso tendrías que adaptarlo un poco, pero podrías utilizar [`d-flex`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) `justify-content-center` y `pb-5` (Padding bottom, puedes cambiarlo a otros valores si el espacio es muy grande).

Ejemplo (Puse una imagen genérica para que se pueda probar):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container bg-primary">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 position-relative border">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center pb-5">
    <span class="rounded-circle">
      <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/002/318/271/original/user-profile-icon-free-vector.jpg" class="rounded-circle img-fluid border-dark border border-1" id="fotocv" alt="">
    </span>
  </div>
  <h1 class="border-bottom border-danger fs-4 pb-2 border-4 rounded text-uppercase" id="nombre">Facundo Nicolas Duran</h1>
  <p>Estudiante de Ingeniería en Sistemas de Información</p>
</div>
```